# Flutter how to use deep links to launch apps on the web

Tags: flutter, dart, deep-linking

I want to launch my app through a link on the web.
I want to use a package called [`uni_link`](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links).

Following the example, I added the following to `AndroidMainfest.xml`.

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="exampletest"
                    android:host="deeplink.exampe.test" />
            </intent-filter>
```

I want the app to launch when a link is clicked on the web.

This is my main source.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:uni_links/uni_links.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  Future<String?> initialLink() async {
    try {
      final initialLink = await getInitialLink();
      return initialLink!;
    } on PlatformException catch (exception){
      print('${exception.message}');
    }
  }
  String deepLinkURL = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    initialLink().then((value) => setState(() {
      deepLinkURL = value!;
    }));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Flutter Deep Linking Sample"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            child: Text(deepLinkURL == null ? "null" : "$deepLinkURL" ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I didn't quite understand the example, so I asked a question. I would appreciate it if you could explain with a simple example!

Answer (score 0):

problem solving!!!

`AndroidMainfest.xml` has been modified as follows. thank you!

```
<meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="deeplink.exampe.test" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Dose it needs to <application>    <activity > ???

Comment: Run the app by identifying it by scheme and host. If it overlaps, it can be used by editing `AndroidMainfest.xml` because it shows all executable apps.